# “Unrecognized App” Android Pay implementation?

Tags: android, android-pay

I'm testing the Android Pay API. I generated the public key by using the command

```
PaymentMethodTokenizationParameters parameters =
            PaymentMethodTokenizationParameters.newBuilder()
                    .setPaymentMethodTokenizationType(PaymentMethodTokenizationType.NETWORK_TOKEN)
                    .addParameter("publicKey", "Key Here")
                    .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `ENVIRONMENT_TEST` to `ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX` for `WalletFragmentOptions`

This is kinda like `PAYPAL SANDBOX` configuration for testing payments.

Comment: `ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX` is deprecated. The `Unrecognized app` message is supposed to show: https://developers.google.com/android-pay/tutorial#code_and_test